# MariaDB 10.2.10 Slave stops on duplicate key error

Tags: mariadb, mysql-error-1062

I've been setting up two Debian Stretch based MariaDB-Server in Master-Master-Replication.

Slave's replication config section is:

```
server-id       = 2226
auto_increment_increment = 1
auto_increment_offset   = 1
log_bin         = /var/tmp/mysql_binlog/mysql-bin.log
log_bin_index       = /var/tmp/mysql_binlog/mysql-bin.log.index
expire_logs_days    = 3
max_binlog_size         = 100M
relay_log       = /var/tmp/mysql_binlog/slave-relay.log
relay_log_index     = /var/tmp/mysql_binlog/slave-relay.log.index
log_slave_updates   = 1
replicate_annotate_row_events = 0
log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1
```

I am experiencing the following error:

```
show slave status\G;

          Relay_Log_File: slave-relay.032025
            Relay_Log_Pos: 14887746
    Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.001119
         Slave_IO_Running: Yes
               Last_Errno: 1062
               Last_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry '71899-single' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default database: 'mydb'. Query: 'INSERT INTO document_reference
                        (document_reference_document_id, document_reference_type, document_reference_value)
                    VALUES (71899, "single", 0)'
```

but:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select * from mydb.document_reference WHERE document_reference_document_id=71899;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

I've looked up the relay log file - there is only one insert statement.

Anyone has an idea what causes duplicate entry error on slave?

Added information:

Master settings:

```
auto_increment_increment     | 1     
auto_increment_offset        | 1     
binlog_format                | MIXED
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE "document_reference" (
"document_reference_document_id" int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
"document_reference_type" enum('single,'multi') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci     
NOT NULL DEFAULT 'single',
"document_reference_value" int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("document_reference_document_id","document_reference_type"))
```

Comment: Is there _already_ a row on the Slave with PK of 71899, 'single'?  What is the value of `auto_increment_increment` on the _Masters_?  Is it RBR or SBR?  Show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE document_reference`

Comment: Hi @RickJames! I just added the information.

Answer (score 0):

When having "dual Master", set

```
auto_increment_increment = 2  -- on both
auto_increment_offset = 1 on one Master, = 2 on the other
```

Also, `server_id` *must* be different on the two Masters (and on any Slaves).  If they are not different, replication goes round and round between the Masters.

Otherwise, inserts on separate Masters can generate the same `AUTO_INCREMENT` values.

However, that does not answer the problem.  (There is no auto_inc involved.)  The only possible answer (I think) is that two of these rows: `(71899, "single", ...)` were inserted.  The absence of evidence of such in the `SELECT` may have to do with `DELETEs`, deadlocks, etc.  (So, I do not have a definite answer.)

Comment: Hi. I ran a general log on the master server and grep-ed through it. There are no other INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statements regarding the same primary key. So if anyone has an idea what went wrong...

Comment: What about the binlog on the Slave?  Perhaps someone wrote directly to the Slave?

Comment: Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE` on both servers -- compare them completely.

Comment: Is exactly the same one both servers.

Comment: I had a further look at the mysqlbinlog. I had to decode base64 and there is the same insert statement in rowbased and statementbased format. I made a new question out of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47650166/mariadb-10-2-10-writing-double-binlog-entries-in-mixed-format